App wont uninstall/install after canceling the install
I was installing Cura slicer and I got a software update notice and decided to update software too. the software updater said it was waiting for something to close, which was the snap store installing cura. so I canceled the cura install so I could install the software update.
now cura shows it's installed in the snap store but doesnt show up under my apps on my system. The snap store also wont let me uninstall it saying "no packages to remove"
I want to install it but I cant install it since it thinks it's already installed. It doesnt show up under the updates tab either.

Any way to fix this by chance? Like is there any files or temporary files that I can delete so snap store will think that the app isnt installed or something?
Edit: (This "fix" doesn't quite answer what problem I have except for the removal of all my installed apps, which I certantly not willing to do. anything else isn't useful to me. Plus it was regarding U16.)

Does this answer your question? How do I remove an incomplete or broken snap installation of nextcloud on a Raspberry Pi?

This sadly does not answer it. The only thing I found that was useful (to some) was the removal of all snap apps. I am not really wanting to do that though

Run the snap list command to check if the Ultimaker Cura application is installed. If Cura is not installed then you can install it from the terminal with the following command.
sudo snap install cura-slicer

To enable detecting removable USB media run the following commands:
sudo snap connect cura-slicer:mount-observe   
sudo snap connect cura-slicer:removable-media

If snap list shows that Cura is installed its icon should appear in the applications dashboard after rebooting the system. Rebooting the system will automatically mount all installed snaps.

Ok, so new problem with this. sudo snap install cura-slicer did indeed install the newest version of cura (4.13.2), while somehow installing the rest of the one that was being installed from the snap store (4.13.0). now BOTH versions (4.13.0 AND 4.13.2) are on my pc, and I still cannot delete the one from the snap store, as it keeps giving me the same error as before: "no packages to remove." even though IT CLEARLY DOES HAVE PACKAGES

snapd keeps two additional old versions of each installed snap package by default for backups in case there is a problem with the newest version. If you launch the Cura app from the terminal with the snap run cura-slicer it will probably launch the latest version and work OK even though the information in the Snap Store about the status of Cura is confusing.
